# How to check for duplicate post similar to Twitter using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Ok, so i have a website that allows users to post content similar to Facebook and twitter. When a user submits a post I want to check if the same content from that user was already submitted in the past 10 hours. If so I want to redirect the user back, with something like "Duplicate Post"

I currently have this to check if a user has posted more than 10 post in the last hour:

```
//Only allow user to post 10 statuses each hour
    $timestamp = time() - 36000;
    $recentStatuses = Status::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->where('created_at', '>', $timestamp)->orWhere('created_at', '=', $timestamp)->skip(0)->take(10)->get();
    if ($recentStatuses->count() <= 9) {
    //post content
}
```

Now I want to check if the user is submitting the same content within the last 10 hour period, similar to how Facebook and twitter prevent from posting the same content to prevent spamming.

Comment: Basically it can be achieved by retrieving the user's posts in last 10 hours, and check if current post content he/she trying to post is the same as those posts

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to that:

```
$recentStatuses->each(function($item) use($request){
    if($item->comment == $request->input('comment'))
    {
         return false;
    }
});
```